# Why does writing to a PostgreSQL database (docker) shows some activity in the Network panel of the system monitor

Tags: networking, docker, postgresql, 22.04

A quick, yet simple question that came to my mind while observing my system monitor (I was curious on the RAM and CPU usage) while writing a massive data set to a PostgreSQL database hosted on my local machine, but inside a docker container: why does writing to a PostgreSQL database  show some activity in the Network panel of the system monitor on Ubuntu 22.04?

[image: Network panel in the Ubuntu system monitor]

The starting of the query perfectly corresponded to the initial rise of the red curve.

Bonus question: why does it reach a "plateau" to roughly 50 MB/s and doesn't go faster?

Comment: How did you make the query? Are you doing it from inside the query, or are you doing it via your local machine, and communicating with the Docker container over [a Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/)? If you're doing it from your machine, chances are that network usage reflects you connecting using the Docker network. IDK why it isn't faster

Comment: The query is actually done from a Python script that is executed on the localhost directly (not within a container). But the writing is done into the database which is histed inside a running [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) container.